# Is verse 21:33 a scientific error?

Tags: science

> Chapter Anbya verse 33 (21:33)
>
> > And He is the One Who created the day and the night, the sun and the moon—each travelling in an orbit.
> > Dr. Mustafa Khattab, the Clear Quran
>
> > And it is He Who created the night and the day, and the sun and the moon, each floating in an orbit.
> > Fadel Soliman, Bridges’ translation
>
> > And He is the One who has created the night and the day, and the sun and the moon, each floating in an orbit.
> > Maarif-ul-Quran

Why is this verse saying that sun and moon float in an orbit. Means that the verse is say that both sun and moon have one orbit.

But sun and moon have two different orbits.

Can anyone explain this verse to me

Comment: you can check the link.. [al-anbiya-verse-33](https://qurano.com/en/21-al-anbiya/verse-33/).. there are many translation and Tafseer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Chapter Anbya verse 33 (21:33)
>
> > And He is the One Who created the day and the night, the sun and the moon—each travelling in an orbit. Dr. Mustafa Khattab, the Clear Quran
>
> > And it is He Who created the night and the day, and the sun and the moon, each floating in an orbit. Fadel Soliman, Bridges’ translation
>
> > And He is the One who has created the night and the day, and the sun and the moon, each floating in an orbit. Maarif-ul-Quran

> Wahuwa allathee khalaqa allayla wannaharawashshamsa walqamara kullun fee falakin yasbahoon
> Transliteration

kullun means
[Meanings](https://arabicwordaday.wordpress.com/2007/06/27/%D9%83%D9%84%D9%91-kullu-%E2%80%93-arabic-word-a-day/) :

*all
totally, entirely
entire, whole*

See the Saheeh International

> And it is He who created the night and the day and the sun and the moon; all [heavenly bodies] in an orbit are swimming.
> Saheeh International(22:33)

All is not used for two objects

> all
>
> used to refer to the whole quantity or extent of a particular group or thing.
> "all the people I met

So this verse is referring to all the plants earth moon sun. And not just sun.